# Using react-slider my labels are not aligning

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is not an issue with this package (react-slider) per se, but I need to use the range slider and have some labels underneath it, the problem being I can't make the label's center align with the handles. See example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/0312l75vpw

The problem is my text offset is obviously different to handle offset. 
I thought to make the width of the labels: calc(100/6) would do the trick but this is not how the handle offset is calculated.

I was looking for suggestions :) What do people think?

Render the offset of labels according to the offset of handles.
I looked at the package's code out how the offset is calculated:

```
 _calcOffset: function (value) { var range = this.props.max - 
 this.props.min; if (range === 0) { return 0; } var ratio = (value - 
 this.props.min) / range; return ratio * this.state.upperBound; } ,
```

I could use this logic to calculate the offset of each label (and use position: absolute for labels too) but the problem IS:
How do I make sure Labels only get rendered after react-slider, as I will need to know its width beforehand etc?

Or does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: Try https://codesandbox.io/s/1061l8m7vl

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, but I think this made even less clear what is being selected?

Comment: I ended up setting an interval to check if horizontal-slider exists, and if it does it render the labels. Not sure if this is the right approach but it works for now:
         
        this.interval = setInterval(() => {
            const slider = document.querySelector('.horizontal-slider');
            if(slider){
                this.setLabels();
            }
        }, 200)
    }